# Get current value of an Angular 17 FormBuilder field not reflecting actual value

Tags: angular, angular-formbuilder

I'm building a string of text in my template from multiple sources. Each of the fields fires it's own change event successfully, but I'm trying to get the value of the `constraint` field from within the change event of the `identifier` field and it's not working. When the change event fires on the `identifier` field, it calls `updateIdentifier` in the `ts` file. But for some reason it's not able to get the current value of the `constraint` field.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-request-user-group',
  templateUrl: './request-user-group.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./request-user-group.component.scss']
})
export class RequestUserGroupComponent implements OnInit {
  requestUserGroupForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
      // The route is /request-user-group
      this.requestUserGroupForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        identifier: ['Identifier'],
        memberConstraint: ['None'],
      }, {});
    }
  }

  updateIdentifierText($event) {
    debugger;
    this.identifier.next($event.target.value);
  }
}
```

and the relevant bits from the template

```
<form [formGroup]="requestUserGroupForm" (ngSubmit)="submitUserGroupRequest_click()">
  <div class="data-field">
    <h2>Identifier</h2>
    <input type="text" (change)="updateIdentifierText($event)" formControlName="identifier">
  </div>
  <div class="data-field">
    <div class="member-constraint-radio">
      <input type="radio" formControlName="memberConstraint" name="memberConstraint" id="member-constraint-None" value="None">
      <label for="member-constraint-None">None</label>
    </div>
    <div class="member-constraint-radio">
      <input type="radio" formControlName="memberConstraint" name="memberConstraint" id="member-constraint-2FA" value="2FA">
      <label for="member-constraint-2FA">2FA</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

If I select the 2FA radio button, then change the identifier to "foo". When the debugger fires in the `updateIdentifierText` I can output the following two lines and get different values. Why is this, and how can I ensure I'm getting the currently selected value?

```
this.requestUserGroupForm.get('memberConstraint').value
// prints None
this.requestUserGroupForm.get('memberConstraint')._pendingValue
// prints 2FA
this.requestUserGroupForm.value.memberConstraint
// prints None
```

**Update:** After reading the suggestion from @Thomas Cayne I decided to fire a change event on the radio buttons which updates a value in the component (just like the identifier event). Then I'm listening to both of those values to update the string of text.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `(input)` instead of `(change)`. `(input)` event fires everytime you enter a character. `(change)` when you lose focus on the input. Or you can do the following:

Use `ChangeDetectorRef` to detect the changes in your component:

```
constructor(
  private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
  private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef
) {}

updateIdentifierText($event) {
   debugger;
   this.identifier.next($event.target.value);
   this.cdRef.detectChanges(); // Trigger change detection

   // Will now reflect the updated value
   console.log(this.requestUserGroupForm.value.memberConstraint);
}
```

Also, I don't see where you are using `submitUserGroupRequest_click()`.